# sessionStorage is not working in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I am working on data collection website. I am using session storage to store session for an event. It is working absolutely fine with Google Chrome but not in Microsoft Edge.

Here is my code.

```
function populateModalData(editButtonId) {
// If first time run, then store data in sessionstorage
if (!((editButtonId + "device1") in sessionStorage)) {
    //device1 radio button
    sessionStorage.setItem(editButtonId + "device1", "true");
    sessionStorage.setItem(editButtonId + "device2", "false");

    //jig radio button
    sessionStorage.setItem(editButtonId + "jig1", "true");
    sessionStorage.setItem(editButtonId + "jig2", "false");

    // up down/under
    sessionStorage.setItem(editButtonId + "up", "true");
    sessionStorage.setItem(editButtonId + "under", "false");

    // Drop down list
    sessionStorage.setItem(editButtonId + "exampleFormControlSelect1", "マミーポコパンツ M");

    // Cond values
    sessionStorage.setItem(editButtonId + "cond1", "140");
    sessionStorage.setItem(editButtonId + "cond2", "130");
    sessionStorage.setItem(editButtonId + "cond3", "100");
    sessionStorage.setItem(editButtonId + "cond4", "75");
    sessionStorage.setItem(editButtonId + "cond5", "50");
}

// Hide video mode
document.getElementById("shootingType").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("videoMode").style.display = "flex";
}
```

How will it work with Microsoft Edge?

Comment: Have you tried it in Firefox? It may or may not be an Edge-specific problem.

Comment: It is working fine on Firefox.

Comment: I guess there is Edge-Specific problem.

Comment: I have even tried to use http://www.tutorialspark.com/html5/HTML5_WebStorage_API_Session_Storage_Demo.php with edge and chrome for testing but again it not working on edge and working perfect with chrome

Comment: I loaded that exact page on Edge and it is working perfectly. My edge is `44.18362.449.0`, you?

Comment: mine is same as yours Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0.

Comment: Can u check Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362 with your edge?

Comment: Please try to run the same program locally. Store the code as .html and run it.

Comment: I will not work

Comment: For security / privacy reasons, Edge does not support `sessionStorage` with `file:///`.

Comment: That's why you need to [create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I stored the file on different PC on my Network and i tried to run it from the there using file link like \\ip_address\Share\toAbhi\sessionStorage.html is working